# How to check whether a row exist corresponding to a value or not through JSTL in Jsp page

Tags: jsp, null, jstl

I have following code in JSP page

```
 <td>
    <c:choose><c:when test="${(row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb) > 0.0}"> 
    <fmt:formatNumber value="${row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" pattern="##.##E0" var="mm"></fmt:formatNumber>
    ${(mm)}
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
    <c:out value="OFF"></c:out></c:otherwise></c:choose></td>
```

Through this code, I check that if row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb >0 ,then it should to trimmed to two decimals and when it is 0 or less then actual value of it is to displayed.

Now I want to check first that whether row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb exist at all or not ,If it does not exist then null should be displayed corresponding to that row. If it exist ,then only above said conditions will be checked

Is this possible through JSTL?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it would look like:

```
<td>
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${empty row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb}"> 
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${(row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb) > 0.0}"> 
        <fmt:formatNumber value="${row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb}" maxFractionDigits="2" minIntegerDigits="2" type="percent" var="mm"/>
        ${mm}
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        ${row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb}
    </c:otherwise>
    </c:choose>
</td>
```

Comment: the value in row.st1_vs1_bag6_rb is coming from a list from java class.Suppose the list has values like 20,30,40  and so on ,then I want to check that if the value is not nearby 10 then null should come in that row in first round,then check it for 20 in neaxt round and so on ..Can I do this in JSTL?

Comment: Yes, but that's a whole 'nother question.  Give it a shot then start a new question once you have some code to demonstrate.